# How to access an aggregate result from a solution in OptaPlanner

Tags: java, drools, optaplanner

## Problem

I would like to evaluate the aggregated value of a solution in a drool rule. For example, in a school scheduling scenario, an employee must not go over 40h/week. How can I implement this scenario in a constraint using the TimeGrain pattern?

## Experimentation

I've made two implementations of this scenario using the EasyScoreCalculator and Drools (see code bellow). The relational model looks like this:
[image: model]

1. The schedule represents a single week.
2. The method getTotalHours(...) returns the total number of hours scheduled during the week.

### EasyScoreCalculator

```java
    public HardSoftScore calculateScore(Schedule schedule) {
        int hardScore = 0;
        int softScore = 0;
        int maxTimePerWeek = 40;

        for (Teacher teacher : schedule.getTeachers()) {
            int totalDuration = Schedule.getTotalHours(schedule.getScheduleTimes(),teacher);
            System.out.println("totalDuration for teacher: " + totalDuration);
            if(totalDuration > maxTimePerWeek)
                softScore += totalDuration - maxTimePerWeek;
        }
        return HardSoftScore.of(hardScore, softScore);
    }
```

### Drools

```java
rule "Teacher should have max 40 hours"
    when
        ScheduleTime(teacher != null, $teacher : teacher)
        Schedule($scheduleTimes: scheduleTimes)

    then
        int totalDuration = Schedule.getTotalHours($scheduleTimes, $teacher);
        System.out.println("totalDuration for teacher: " + totalDuration);
        if( totalDuration > 40){
            scoreHolder.penalize(kcontext, totalDuration - 40);
        }
end
```

The drool file is correctly configured as other constraints are working properly.

## Result

The first solution works well, but according to the documentation, the EasyScoreCalculator might cause performance issues.

The second doesn't work as the console output never gets executed. However, if I remove `Schedule($scheduleTimes: scheduleTimes)` and the related code, the "then" clause gets executed. How can I get the aggregated result of the scenario for this case in the Drools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In drools you can use the accumulate which is going to do a group by on the specific teacher (I've assumed you have an id in your Teacher object so you can group by a specific teacher and a minutes in your ScheduleTime).  Here's a more detailed write up on accumulate  http://blog.athico.com/2009/06/how-to-implement-accumulate-functions.html and https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.2.0.Final/drools-docs/html/ch07.html (search for "accumulate").  This check will be performed on all the Teacher instances.

The "when" condition should be matched when the aggregate of the assignments for a teacher is greater than 40 hours.  There is not need to put the condition in the then since it has been filtered in the "when".
`
    when
        $teacher : Teacher( $tId:id != null)

```
    $totalMinutes: Long(longValue > 40 * 60 )       
    accumulate( 
        ScheduleTime( 
            teacher != null, 
            teacher.id == $tId
        ),sum(minutes)
    )   
then    

    System.out.println("totalDuration for teacher: " + $totalMinutes/60);
    scoreHolder.penalize(kcontext, $totalMinutes/60- 40);
```

`